# Which thread will run a method of a TThread instance? (In Wait mode)

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi, synchronization, delphi-6

- When a TThread enters in `Synchronized()` method, it waits until `EnterCriticalSection(ThreadLock)` returns.

Now, which one will run the method if in the meantime, another Tthread, or even the main thread call some method of the waiting Tthread?

Comment: Perhaps you could give a concrete example of what you want to call. For example, it's not safe to call `Free`. If you give a concrete example there's less scope for mis-understanding. Without a concrete example, there's no single answer. Some methods will be fine to call, some will not. It depends. Is that the answer you want? I doubt it very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could happen if in the meantime, another thread, or even the main thread call some method of the waiting thread?

Threads do not have methods, so this question is a non-sequitur.

It is not meaningful to ask what happens when you call a method of another thread. Because it is not possible to do so.  When you call a method, that method executes on thread which called it.

A method like `TThread.Synchronize` *schedules* the execution of code onto a different thread. But, the body of `TThread.Synchronize` is executed by the thread of the caller.

A call to `EnterCriticalSection` cannot be interrupted by user mode code. So, suppose that thread A calls `EnterCriticalSection` at a point where thread B holds the lock. The call to `EnterCriticalSection` made on thread A will not return until thread B has released the lock. While thread A is blocked waiting to acquire the lock, no code will execute on thread A.

---

It seems, from clarifications in the comments, that your question is in fact:

> When a method of `TThread` is called, on which thread does that method execute?

The answer is that the method is executed on the calling thread. There's nothing special about the `TThread` class and so the normal rules apply.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. TThread inherites from TObject, so It can of course have methods. Thread's itself don't have methods, I should edit the question.

Comment: I don't think I misunderstood what you wrote. Perhaps what you wrote was not what you meant. For sure `TThread` has methods. But that's not what you wrote. You wrote "method of the waiting thread". There's a big difference between the class `TThread` and a *thread*.

Comment: I know that, and you already answered what I wanted to know, you said that is executed in the context of the caller. The TThread is a wrapper of BeginThread (on windows).

Comment: OK, so is your question about which thread will run a method of a `TThread` instance? If that's the question then the answer is, as you say above, it runs on whichever thread makes the call.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Now, I realise that I have the incredible ability to make question very much confused to tiny problems

Comment: Thanks @David, I'm was messy with question, actually I believe is because of lack of fluency in English language, that sometimes make I choose words that has different meaning for fluent people

Comment: No probs. I'm glad I was able to help even if only a little.